# How to handle errors in my form fields with a single function in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-material-ui-form-validator

I have a form where the user needs to answer 3 questions to be able to register a new password. All fields are mandatory, and the user is unable to send the data to the server until the 3 questions are answered.

My question is how to handle input field errors with only one function? I currently perform a function for each of the fields. And this is not very good at performance levels.

For example, with just one function I can get the values entered in all input fields:

```js
const handleChangeField = (field) => (event) => {
  const value = event?.target?.value || "";
  setData((prev) => ({ ...prev, [field]: value }));
};
```

Can you tell me if it is possible to create a function similar to the one above, but to handle errors? In this moment that's what I'm doing:

```js
<TextField
  label="What is your mother's name?"
  className={classes.input}
  error={hasErrorMother}
  helperText={hasErrorMother ? "Required field*" : ""}
  value={data.motherName}
  onInput={(event) =>
    event.target.value.length > 0
      ? setHasErrorMother(false)
      : setHasErrorMother(true)
  }
  onChange={handleChangeField("motherName")}
/>
```

I handle errors for each of the fields within `onInput`.

Here's the code I put into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/handle-fields-erros-7o7mb?file=/src/App.js)

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea: you keep using `handleChangeField` but with a few modifications to also handle the `error` as well. But first, we need to change the state title bit:

```
// Remove those
// const [hasErrorMother, setHasErrorMother] = useState(false);
// const [hasErrorBorn, setHhasErrorBorn] = useState(false);
// const [hasErrorPet, setHasErrorPet] = useState(false);

// Instead have the error state this way
const [error, setError] = useState({
  motherName: false,
  birthplace: false,
  petName: false
});

...
// handleChangeField will have an extra line for error handling
const handleChangeField = (field) => (event) => {
  const value = event?.target?.value || "";
  setData((prev) => ({ ...prev, [field]: value }));
  setError((prev) => ({ ...prev, [field]: value.length === 0 })); // THIS ONE
};
```

And in the return statement, the `TextField` will change to be:

```
// onInput is removed, because onChange is taking care of the error
<TextField
  label="What is your mother's name?"
  className={classes.input}
  error={error.motherName}
  helperText={error.motherName? "Required field*" : ""}
  value={data.motherName}
  onChange={handleChangeField("motherName")}
/>
```

Now for the `handleContinueAction`, this will also change as follows:

```
...
const handleContinueAction = () => {
  const isValid =
    data.motherName.length > 0 &&
    data.birthplace.length > 0 &&
    data.petName.length > 0;

  if (isValid) {
    console.log("Ok, All data is valid, I can send this to the server now");
  } else {
    // If you want to show error for the incomplete fields
    setError({
      motherName: data.motherName.length === 0,
      birthplace: data.birthplace.length === 0,
      petName: data.petName.length === 0
    })
  }
};

...
// and git rid of this part
// const validateFields = (body) => {
//   if (body.motherName.length === 0) {
//     return setHasErrorMother(true);
//   }

//   if (body.birthplace.length === 0) {
//     return setHhasErrorBorn(true);
//   }

//   if (body.petName.length === 0) {
//     return setHasErrorPet(true);
//   }

//   return true;
};
```

Comment: Hey Akram, thank you for your help, I did what you say, but when I press the button, no one error show for the user, look my codesandbox updated: https://codesandbox.io/s/handle-fields-erros-7o7mb?file=/src/Form/Form.jsx

Comment: When you press the button, it will only do the `console.log` if `isValid` is correct. If you want to display an error message for the fields if `isValid` is false then you could add an `else` statement simiral to the one I just put in my edited answer

Comment: Perfecty!!! Not that works perfectly!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: Happy to help :)